# Save and replay users actions in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

Use case I want to cover is to **persist** all actions/state of a redux application **users' session**. When required I can query a particular session from the storage and load this in my local running application.

I am looking for tools/libs I can chain together for this purpose.

https://github.com/michaelcontento/redux-storage is used for persisting/loading application state in localStorage (or a native alternative) so it seems to serve a different purpose.

What I am basically looking for is a redux alternative for https://github.com/auth0/react-flux-debug-actions-sample

I was thinking I could start the app like this:

```
DEBUG=true SESSION_ID=<somebody's session id> node index.js
```

inside the app:

```
var debugState = {};
if (process.env.DEBUG) debugState = findState(process.env.SESSION_ID);
```

push this `debugState` down the redux app:

```
createStore(reducer, [debugState]);
```

Then all the debug tools (such as the suggested `redux-devtools`) can serve to replay state.

Not sure about this though. Any input/experience is welcome.

Comment: Did you test redux-devtools ? https://github.com/gaearon/redux-devtools

Comment: Sure, in development ;) let me update the question a bit

Comment: You might consider architecting your application to use an immutable database for storage; [Datomic](http://www.datomic.com/) is the one getting all the buzz right now